# derivatives of coordinates on a riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, differential-forms

Let $X$ be a compact connected Riemann surface of genus $g>0$. Let $(\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_g)$ be a basis for $H^0(X,\Omega^1)$.

Let $x$ be a point in $X$ and let $z:U\longrightarrow B(0,1)$ be a local coordinate, where $U$ is an open in $X$ containing $x$ and $B(0,1)$ is the open unit disc in $\mathbf{C}$.

For any $i$, there is a (holomorphic?) function  $f_i:U\to \mathbf{C}$ such that $\omega_i = (f_i\circ z) dz$ on $U$.

Now, we have that $\omega_i \wedge \overline{\omega_i} = \vert f_i \vert^2 dz \wedge d\overline{z}$.

How does the derivative $f_i^\prime = df_i/dz$ relate to $\omega_i$?

More precisely, is there a connection between $$\left\vert\frac{df_i}{dz}\right\vert(0)$$ and $\omega_i$?